# How to retrieve shortcode url using php preg-match-all in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, preg-match-all

Im trying to get the url or lets say a part of the sortcode in wordpress.

```
[button link="#" text="Join Now!"]
```

The above shortcode is coming with the `$content = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'mycontent', true );`

I tried to use the following:

```
preg_match_all('\blink="(.+)\b', $content, $matches);

<div class="container">
    <a href="<?php echo $matches[0]; ?>"> <!-- trying to get the url here -->
      <h3><?php echo the_title(); ?></h3>
      <?php if($content!='') {
        echo apply_filters('the_content', get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'mycontent', true ));
      } ?>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Do you have any idea how can I do it because the preg_match_all is giving me the following error.

**preg_match_all(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in**

Answer (score 0):

Try Following.

```
$content = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'mycontent', true );
preg_match_all('/\[button link([^>]+)\]/',$content,$matches);

 OR

preg_match_all('/\[button link="(.*)" text="(.*)"\]/',$content,$matches);

print_r($matches);
print_r($matches[1]); //It will give shortcode url.
```

Comment: Krishna thanks I'm not sure why its returning to array instead I tried your both methods but I'm getting an output like `<a href="Array">`

Comment: because It is returning array in $matches[0] and you had echo it. first print your array using print_r and than pass necessary array value.

Comment: So, maybe required another way to retreive url from a part(database) of a shortcode

Answer (score 0):

Your regex `\blink="(.+)\b` will match `link="` and then captures any character 1+ times in a capturing group followed by a word boundary.

That will match `#" text="Join Now` because the last position where a word boundary can match is between `w!`

You could use a capturing group to get the value for blink and use [delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) for the regex:

`\[button .*?\blink="([^"]+)".*?\]`

```
$re = '~\[button .*?\blink="([^"]+)".*?\]~';
$str = '[button link="#" text="Join Now!"]';
preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
echo $matches[1]; // #
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/r3S6J2/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/CuIg4)

Comment: this one is working but $str is allways changing since its a wordpress post type and the custom field is allways changing with different values, link or text. So its allways adding # in the url

Comment: @AlbanoAlbanese Can you give some more examples for `$str` that should match and which should not match?

Comment: @AlbanoAlbanese Try `$re = '~\[.*?\blink="([^"])+"[^]]+]~';` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cG5O4n/1)

Comment: thanks for your try but looks like impossible I tried this and many other ways but its  allways showing # instead the given url I added `https://google.com` as url but allways its giving the value of `$str`

Comment: @AlbanoAlbanese In your example data there is no url present, only `#`. Where is the url located? What does the data look like?